# What's wrong with this Response.Redirect Query String

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to Reponse.Redirect to an error page that will be used for three types of sources. When I run this QueryString, it doesn't go to the page. It generates the generic ASP.NET error page.

```
Response.Redirect("~/dispatch/NoStationError.aspx?Name=" + thisStation + "&Type=" + "Station");
```

thisStation is a string

Comment: What's the error that you get?

Comment: put a break point in your global.asax.cs  Application_Error method... and you should see what the error is.

Comment: That showed it. I guess I have to put a ContentPlaceHolder Utilities.LastError = {"Cannot find ContentPlaceHolder 'head' in the master page '/RICQ32013_OKL_3000/MasterPage.master', verify content control's ContentPlaceHolderID attribute in the content page."}

Comment: Nope. I don't know why its displaying this error. My page I am redirecting to doesn't reference a Master page and only has a label! The code I am doing this from is a custom control referenced from the master page though.

Comment: If I set that breakpoint in global.asax Application_Error method, how do I get the actual error? I was reading Utilities.LastError = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException(); which I think was an unrelated error. Is there anything wrong with my query string construction?

Comment: Dumb. The last error told me the page did not exist. I had renamed the page from NoStationError to StationError.